# Loading Laravel application from Zend application

Tags: php, laravel, zend-framework

We have an application built on top of Zend Framework. We are revamping one of its module in laravel.
Let say, http://foo.com loads ZF application by default.

How would I load the laravel application from ZF if user enters http://foo.com/bar

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what you tried up to now?

Comment: @DeepKakkar: I am new to ZF, so finding a way to load Laravel application from ZF frontcontroller when the particular module is called

Comment: Can't you just put the laravel installation into a folder in your "public"?

Comment: @Valdorous: How would we start the Laravel application from there? I don't know if is it a right way by placing the laravel installation folder inside ZF public folder. It will add tight coupling

Comment: It is the simplest solution, another would be to add a symlink in the ZF public leading to Laravel's public index. (I work in The ZF everyday, but prefer Laravel). What do you mean with tight coupling?

Comment: As to how you would "start" it, you would need to make sure that the Zend public/bar links to the laravel/public (possible via .htaccess, symlink, etc). 

That would mean buy visiting http://foo.com/bar you would be accessing your laravel installation.

Answer (score 0):

In order to load laravel on http://foo.com/bar, you need to make certain changes in your server configuration file. Below code could be useful if you using NGINX web server

```
server {
    listen   80 default_server;
    root ABSOLUTE PATH OF LARAVEL PUBLIC DIR ;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    location /bar {
       try_files $uri $uri/bar /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
}
```

You can also run Laravel standalone (http://baz.com) and let it act as an API endpoint provider eg: (http://baz.com/module1). This should return some date (JSON/XML)

Your zend application route (http://foo.com/bar) will make an API request to your module (http://baz.com/module1) and consume the data.